# How to sum nested array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
var dataSheet = [
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}],
]
```

I would like to sum all the price and a result like this

```
result = [[600], [400], [200]]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why the nested array? Instead of simply `[600, 400, 200]`

Comment: the `dataSheet ` is dynamic, thanks  for your comment

Comment: Yes, but I was talkinng about the expected result, not about the dataSheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Principle is the same for both nested and flat arrays: just use `reduce` to get sum of values in array.
In your case you just need to apply this mechanism to each nested array in your `dataSheet` and receive new array of values. Method `map` is designed exactly creating new array based on values from the source array.

So the correct answer would be to use combination of `map` and `reduce`.

```js
var dataSheet = [
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}],
]

var result = dataSheet.map(data => data.reduce((acc, obj) => acc += obj.price,0));
console.log(result); // [600, 400, 200]
```

If you really need to have result like `[[600],[400],[200]]` (embedded arrays instead of just values, you just need to wrap returned values in `[]`, like this:

```js
var dataSheet = [
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}],
]

var result = dataSheet.map(data => [data.reduce((acc, obj) => acc += obj.price,0)]);
console.log(result); // [[600], [400], [200]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.map()` along with `.forEach()` function.

```js
var dataSheet = [
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}],
]

const res = dataSheet.map(arr => {
  let sum = 0;
  arr.forEach(obj => sum += obj.price);
  return [sum];
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `map` + `reduce` is what you are looking for :)

```
const res = dataSheet.map(el => el.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.price, 0));
```

Or `flatMap` if you need result as [600, 400, 200]:

```
const res = dataSheet.flatMap(el => el.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.price, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`, `reduce` and destructuring.

```js
var dataSheet = [
  [{ price: 200 }, { price: 200 }, { price: 200 }],
  [{ price: 200 }, { price: 200 }],
  [{ price: 200 }],
];

const result = dataSheet.map((arr) =>
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce(({ price: acc }, { price }) => ({ price: acc + price }))
  )
);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataSheet = [
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}, {price: 200}],
    [{price: 200}],
];

var res = dataSheet.reduce((result, row) => 
  result.concat([[row.reduce((sum, element) => 
    sum + element.price, 0)]]), []);

console.log(res);
```